# Which were the first PhD thesis in Mathematics and Physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Were there PhD thesis in the time of Galileo and Newton?

Did Newton and Galileo make a PhD thesis?

Due to the poor level of science (before calculus and so on), were PhD thesis made in math and physics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/index.php):

Galileo Galilei was a student of Ostilio Ricci

The official tutor of Isaac Newton (M.A.) was Benjamin Pulleyn
; Isaac Barrow was NOT a formal advisor but probably had the greatest influence on the young Newton

But neither of these held the actual title "Ph.D."...[History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy)

If Erhard Weigel (1652) is indeed the first Ph.D. (as some have suggested), then that would be mathematics.